# Image sent from flask mail can't be visualized

Tags: python, html, email, flask, flask-mail

I have an application that uses `Flask` and `Flask-mail`. I am trying to send an email with and image attached. This image is sent from a user through a form in `html`. The email arrives but the image cant be visualized when its open in the email.

My code is:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
            file = request.files['arch']
            if request.files['arch'].filename != '':
                if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
                    filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
                    file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))

                    fic = open( "uploads/" + file.filename, "r", encoding='utf8', errors='ignore')

                    msg.attach("uploads/" + file.filename, "image/png", fic.read())

        mail.send(msg)
```

for the html:

```
<form action="/form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="arch" accept="image/*" class="arch">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the line `fic` onwards try following changes.

```
with app.open_resource(UPLOAD_FOLDER) as test:
        msg.attach(UPLOAD_FOLDER, 'image/jpg', test.read())
    mail.send(msg)
```